# Design help clocked synchronous state machine

Tags: clock, synchronous

This is the problem that I must solve with my own numbers 00000010 in my case.

[image: Problem]

Here is where I am at

> [image: Transition Table]

> [image: Transition Table]

> [image: Kmaps]

> [image: Kmaps]

> [image: Kmaps]

[Input Code](https://paste.ofcode.org/xunxaxGZdexvJQCdwWgt6h)

Based on my design, my z state should never go high unless my y state gives 2 lows then a high on the 3rd clock and then more lows till the 9th clock.

[image: Designed output]

However, based on the output code my z state goes high on the 3rd clock regardless.

[image: Actual output]

Can anyone explain where I have gone wrong for this to happen?

Comment: Hi, yes sampled on rising edge.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting your state machine requires that you have at least one rising edge for which `X` is low.

Without that, your `Q0` ... `Q3` state variables have unknown/arbitrary values — this would have been obvious if you had simply looked at them.

That's the first lesson in debugging: If the output doesn't produce the result you expect, you need to look at the signals that are used to produce the output. If any of them don't look right, then look at the signals that they depend on, and so on.

---

However, that isn't your main problem. I apologize, I should have picked up on this sooner. In Verilog, there is a subtle difference between two types of assignment within an `initial` or `always` block. In your code, you have

```
  reg Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3;
    
  always @(posedge clk) 
  begin
    Q0 = ... ;
    Q1 = ... ;
    Q2 = ... ;
    Q3 = ... ;
  end
```

The `=` operator is called "blocking assignment", which means that the assignment takes effect right away, rather than waiting until all other assignments have been evaluated and then taking effect after that. In other words, when it comes time to evaluate the expression for `Q1`, the variable `Q0` has already been updated, which leads to a result other than what you were expecting.

On the other hand, the `<=` is called "non-blocking assignment", which means that all assignments within a block are evaluated in parallel before any of the left-hand sides are updated. Switching to this kind of assignment gives the results you're expecting.

````
  reg Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3;
    
  always @(posedge clk) 
  begin
    Q0 <= ... ;
    Q1 <= ... ;
    Q2 <= ... ;
    Q3 <= ... ;
  end
```
````

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for getting back to me. i dont think this is the solution or im missing what you are trying to say to me, see edit to my post.

Comment: What I am saying is **look at the signals inside your state machine**. There's no point in guessing if you can observe them directly.

Comment: Ok Dave still lost talk to me like I'm 5. Signals inside my state machine which one? What am I observing? For context to my edit. I'm setting my X and y values manually.

Comment: You have designed a state machine that has four internal state variables, Q0, Q1, Q2 and Q3. You have written equations that define their behavior for various input combinations, and your output signal depends on their values. You need to put those four signals into your simulator output window so that you can see whether they are behaving on a cycle-by-cycle basis the way you expect.

Comment: Hi Dave, I have just edited my post again with the output with the Q states shown, from my point of view looks like my first clock cycle with all my states going high seems wrong???

Comment: So, do they look right to you? Should they all go high after the second clock edge? It seems like this might be an important clue. What simulator are you using, anyway?

Comment: dont look right to me i would expect some sort of this then that kind of logic. (this being new to me) quartus II Simulation waveform editor (altera???)

Comment: See edit above. I had to run the simulation myself before I realized what the problem is.

Comment: That seems to have solved my problem thanks Dave. Appreciate the help and the explaination.